# Back to Top links on Answers

Tags: feature-request, design

Pretty basic question, can we get #top links on the answers, maybe on the bottom right corner of the original answer text?  I think it would make browsing the really long threads much easier.

Comment: Page Up/Home keys don't work on your keyboard?

Comment: Now now Ian, we can't have that. It is well established fact that every idea must be implemented, regardless of whether or not it is already available using some other widely available method.

Comment: @Ian: You keyboard-elitists think that everyone is using a keyboard.  So typical.  Some of us only have a mouse and type with the character map, you insensitive clod.

Comment: Ian:  I prefer #top links because I use the mouse primarily for navigation, and if I don't have to move my hands to the keyboard, it makes things quicker.

Comment: I'm with you here, phuion - I love a good "top" link :) See my solution below if you're a firefox user.

Comment: I just scroll. Yeah ... I'm not lazy. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using [this greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10184/script-back-to-top-link-from-answers-closed).

Comment: Thanks, I just installed it and its great.